# How can I modify Grant Pauls's Shimmer control so the mask responds to accelerometer input?

Tags: ios, core-motion, caanimation

How can I modify [Grant Pauls's cool Shimmer control](https://github.com/facebook/Shimmer) to respond to accelerometer input? I am a novice with iOS dev and have isolated parts of the code, but I'm not sure how to go about "hooking it up" so it responds to accelerometer input like the sketch below:

(I made the sketch before finding the Shimmer control, the "White Stripe" here would be the non-masked layer of the control)

**EDIT**: I'm not looking for completed code, just ideas on how to approach creating the code. CAAnimation and Core Motion are totally new to me. "Make x a delegate of y and look at line z of the posted code" for instance would qualify as an answer to me.

[image]

Here is the code that I believe would be involved in "hooking up" the accelerometer:

```
  BOOL disableActions = [CATransaction disableActions];
  if (!_shimmering) {
    if (disableActions) {
      // simply remove mask
      [self _clearMask];
    } else {
      // end slide
      CFTimeInterval slideEndTime = 0;

      CAAnimation *slideAnimation = [_maskLayer animationForKey:kFBShimmerSlideAnimationKey];
      if (slideAnimation != nil) {
        // determing total time sliding
        CFTimeInterval now = CACurrentMediaTime();
        CFTimeInterval slideTotalDuration = now - slideAnimation.beginTime;

        // determine time offset into current slide
        CFTimeInterval slideTimeOffset = fmod(slideTotalDuration, slideAnimation.duration);

        // transition to non-repeating slide
        CAAnimation *finishAnimation = shimmer_slide_finish(slideAnimation);

        // adjust begin time to now - offset
        finishAnimation.beginTime = now - slideTimeOffset;

        // note slide end time and begin
        slideEndTime = finishAnimation.beginTime + slideAnimation.duration;
        [_maskLayer addAnimation:finishAnimation forKey:kFBShimmerSlideAnimationKey];
      }

      // fade in text at slideEndTime
      CABasicAnimation *fadeInAnimation = shimmer_end_fade_animation(self, _maskLayer.fadeLayer, 1.0, _shimmeringEndFadeDuration);
      fadeInAnimation.beginTime = slideEndTime;
      [_maskLayer.fadeLayer addAnimation:fadeInAnimation forKey:kFBFadeAnimationKey];

      // expose end time for synchronization
      _shimmeringFadeTime = slideEndTime;
    }
  } else {
    // fade out text, optionally animated
    CABasicAnimation *fadeOutAnimation = nil;
    if (_shimmeringBeginFadeDuration > 0.0 && !disableActions) {
      fadeOutAnimation = shimmer_begin_fade_animation(self, _maskLayer.fadeLayer, 0.0, _shimmeringBeginFadeDuration);
      [_maskLayer.fadeLayer addAnimation:fadeOutAnimation forKey:kFBFadeAnimationKey];
    } else {
      BOOL innerDisableActions = [CATransaction disableActions];
      [CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];

      _maskLayer.fadeLayer.opacity = 0.0;
      [_maskLayer.fadeLayer removeAllAnimations];

      [CATransaction setDisableActions:innerDisableActions];
    }

    // begin slide animation
    CAAnimation *slideAnimation = [_maskLayer animationForKey:kFBShimmerSlideAnimationKey];

    // compute shimmer duration
    CGFloat length = 0.0f;
    if (_shimmeringDirection == FBShimmerDirectionDown ||
        _shimmeringDirection == FBShimmerDirectionUp) {
      length = CGRectGetHeight(_contentLayer.bounds);
    } else {
      length = CGRectGetWidth(_contentLayer.bounds);
    }
    CFTimeInterval animationDuration = (length / _shimmeringSpeed) + _shimmeringPauseDuration;

    if (slideAnimation != nil) {
      // ensure existing slide animation repeats
      [_maskLayer addAnimation:shimmer_slide_repeat(slideAnimation, animationDuration, _shimmeringDirection) forKey:kFBShimmerSlideAnimationKey];
    } else {
      // add slide animation
      slideAnimation = shimmer_slide_animation(self, animationDuration, _shimmeringDirection);
      slideAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
      slideAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
      slideAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + fadeOutAnimation.duration;
      [_maskLayer addAnimation:slideAnimation forKey:kFBShimmerSlideAnimationKey];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should really post you attempts to do this yourself, now you looks like a code request which is really frowned-up and might get your question down voted,

Comment: Understood, but I'm not looking for completed code, just ideas on how to approach creating the code. CAAnimation and Core Motion are totally new to me. Maybe I'm misunderstanding what can/can't be asked on SO.

Answer (score 0):

When you -init your view, you will want to create a MotionManager like so:

```
    self.motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
    [self.motionManager startAccelerometerUpdates];
```

On -dealloc in that view you will also want to get rid of it:

```
    [self.motionManager stopAccelerometerUpdates];
    self.motionManager = nil;
```

Here is the part that will matter most for you, you will need to query the motion manager for updates as to device orientation. I have always done this in the context of a SpriteKit scene in the update method, but I am pretty sure you can add a motion manager delegate (or something) and accomplish the same thing. The important bits are as follows:

```
CMAccelerometerData* data = self.motionManager.accelerometerData;
CGFloat xacceleration = data.acceleration.x;
CGFloat yacceleration = data.acceleration.y;
```

Using that x/y acceleration you can map that to a point in your view and map the shimmer effect to that point.  I hope that helps.